# How to differentiate the following equation?

Tags: derivatives

$$y=\frac{\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ}{\sec x^\circ - \tan x^\circ}$$

I believe formula for u/v must be used but I get stuck up, can somebody explain please.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the ° mean?

Comment: Degrees I believe. x°=pi(x)/180

Comment: Do you mean $\sec x + \frac{\tan x}{\sec x} - \tan x$, or do you mean $\frac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x - \tan x}$?

Comment: 2nd one but x° should be used which would be substituted with pi(x)/180 later on.

Answer (score 1):

$$y=\dfrac{\sec x^\circ+\tan x^\circ}{\sec x^\circ-\tan x^\circ}=\dfrac{(\sec x^\circ+\tan x^\circ)^2}{\sec^2x^\circ-\tan^2x^\circ}$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2(\sec x^\circ+\tan x^\circ)(\sec x^\circ\tan x^\circ+\sec^2x^\circ)\cdot\dfrac\pi{180}$$

$$=\dfrac{\pi\sec x^\circ}{90}\cdot(\sec x^\circ+\tan x^\circ)^2$$

$$=\dfrac{\pi\sec x^\circ}{90}\cdot\dfrac{\sec x^\circ+\tan x^\circ}{\sec x^\circ-\tan x^\circ}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\frac{\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ}{\sec x^\circ - \tan x^\circ}$$
Now multiply numerator and denominator by $sec x° + tan x°$
We get
$$y=\frac{({\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ})^2}{\sec^2 x^\circ - \tan^2 x^\circ}$$
Using the fact that ${\sec^2 x^\circ - \tan^2 x^\circ} =1 $ 
$$y= ({\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ})^2 $$
Differentiating both sides
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= 2({\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ})({\sec x^\circ \tan x^\circ + \sec^2 x^\circ}) × \frac{π}{180}$$ 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{π}{90} \sec x^\circ ({\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ})({\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ})$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{π}{90} \sec x^\circ ({\sec x^\circ + \tan x^\circ})^2 $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{πy}{90} \sec x^\circ $$